# Where to find information about Nautilus D-Bus interface

Tags: dbus, nautilus

I am planning to develop a command line application that interact with Nautilus, but I cannot find a reference for the D-Bus interface that Nautilus exposes.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, the only DBUS interface that nautilus implements is this:

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found any doc on this either, at least you can use sth like d-feet to find out what interface/method/etc. nautilus has.

(and I don't think there are a lot of useful functions~~)