# Copying files with native file manager in python

Tags: python, copy, cross-platform, pywin32, win32com

Okay, so I'm developing an application that will allow users to select file objects in a menu and will allow them to copy said selections to another location. I have so far managed to use the pywin32 module to allow me to copy files using Windows' native file copier.

The code for it:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
srcstr = chr( 0 ).join( [ file[0] for file in files ] )
deststr = chr( 0 ).join( [ file[1] for file in files ] )
shell.SHFileOperation(
    ( 0, shellcon.FO_COPY, srcstr, deststr, shellcon.FOF_MULTIDESTFILES, None, None )
)
```

This is a fine method for copying under Windows, but I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish the same goal under Mac and/or Linux.

Comment: do you need to just copy the files or the meta data as well?

Comment: indeed - from your question I get the feeling you want the metadata as well, otherwise you can use shutil: http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the metadata, I just don't want the actual copying to be handled by Python; I want to offload it to the file manager. (The problem I'm facing is I only know how to do this on Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac, you'll need to script Finder.

One way to do this is with ScriptingBridge. To start with:

```
import ScriptingBridge
f = ScriptingBridge.SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.Finder")
```

Then… well, fire up AppleScript Editor, look at Finder's Dictionary, and figure out how to translate that from AppleScript into Python+ScriptingBridge, and if you have any problems, come back and ask again. But here are some hints:

The trick is to get from a path to a Finder reference. And there's no easy way to get there directly. Instead, you have to start with startupDisk, call folders() on it, filter for name == the first component of path, and repeat. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ScriptingBridgeFinder/Listings/Controller_m.html (which is written in Objective C, not Python, but the ScriptingBridge parts are pretty easy to translate).

Comment: This doesn't seem like too much work, considering the daunting task of trying to provide alternatives for every Linux distro. (Makes my eyes roll) I'm just going to leave Linux to the fallback and concentrate on Mac, so I'll definitely be looking into this sometime tomorrow. Thank you a whole lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered shutil (http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)? This module provides that sort of high-level file operations while remaining os-agnostic.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a solution that will use the operating system's graphic file manager to copy the files. For instance, this is what the example code looks like running on Windows 7; [example_image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971642/shellcopy.png "Example")

Comment: For MAC you can look at [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net). For Linux you will not find one solution that works for all, since there are a lot of diferent distributions and the GUI is different for each.

Comment: Hm, I didn't even think about using PyObjC... I figured as much for Linux; I'll probably just look up a console interface for nautilus since I use Ubuntu the most. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do this on Mac is with NSWorkspace via PyObjC. Like this:

```
from Cocoa import *
ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
ws.performFileOperation_source_destination_files_tag_(NSWorkspaceCopyOperation,
    '/dirname/of/source', '/dest/directory', ['basenameOfSource'], None)
```

The problem is that this isn't actually guaranteed to do the same thing as the Finder. For large copies, it usually will, but for smaller copies there may be no feedback at all.

Also, if you want to get any feedback, you have to stash ret[1] and register for the NSWorkspace notification NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification, which means you need a run loop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will likely be OS/desktop-specific; for instance on GNOME, you'd need to use DBus to communicate with Nautilus.

Someone asked about documentation and apparently there wasn't any: [Where to find information about Nautilus D-Bus interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997680/where-to-find-information-about-nautilus-d-bus-interface)

and this thread indicates that the features you need might exist in the current version of Nautilus:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/52093/how-can-i-initiate-nautilus-file-operations-from-the-command-line

but to support OS X, KDE, etc. you might have to do work for each.

Answer (score 0):

I don't envy the task. To achieve this you aren't so much targetting "Linux" but desktop environment X, Y, Z, etc (and the different versions of each). It isn't just KDE vs. Gnome, it's KDE 3/4 vs Gnome 2/3 vs Enlightment vs Xfce4 vs Blackbox vs. TWM and others.

You can get a cross-desktop file picker using a library like GTK or WXwidgets but I don't think either of those has a progress widget for copy operations (you'd have to code that yourself) and they don't look "native" either.

Speaking generally though I don't think a native copy dialog is really something most linux users would care about. We're used to programs looking different and we learn to live with it.

Anyway, I'd recommend [GtkProgressBar](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkProgressBar.html) or [wxProgressDialog](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxprogressdialog.html) since either should be reasonably easy to put to this task and both libraries have python bindings.

Comment: Well it's a good thing I already coded a fallback in pure python, because this seems like too much work for the utility that I'm making. (And the fallback's progress bar is pretty good looking too...)